# backgroundThread not working in compact framework 3.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-3.0, compact-framework

I am trying to run a thread or process at background,that is on clicking Send button files from the local device should send to shared folder of PC.This is working fine but now the user need to wait until all the files send to PC,which takes long time since they may send min 30 to max 50 files.User is not able to move other screen also.What i required is after hit Send button the file sending process should happen background and user should navigate to any other task if they like.I tried the below code,but it is not giving any error,

```
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread backgroundThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(WriteOutEvents));
        backgroundThread.IsBackground = true;
        backgroundThread.Start();
    }


        private void WriteOutEvents()
        {
         ///////////
        }
```

I debugged and it is reading the  three line in OnClosing() method and not comming to WriteOutEvents() method.So by this way the files are not transferred to PC since it is not calling the  WriteOutEvents() method.

Need help to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your problem but you should create your thread somewhere where you can access it after your form is gone. That way you still have control over it, can see if it is still running and stop it if you need to.

Comment: Yes, you should crete your thread in a global class and not in the OnClosing event. What is writeoutevents() code? Does it reference form elements or other windows? Possibly you should run a global background thread or another process that shares a queue of objects to send. I have done similar with sending files via ftp and just used a folder that is watched.